# How do I use new AWS Amplify Authenticator flow with React Context?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-amplify, react-context

The last time I looked at Authentication in AWS Amplify each authentication step had a request and response.  I stored the responses in a authentication global react context.

Now it appears there is a WYSIWYG widget that handles everything -- Authenticator
(https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/configuration).

The documentation focuses on UI customization but does not deep dive into the responses.  For example, when someone signs up I want to set their account to "pending" until they enter the email authentication code sent to their email address.  obviously if they leave the signup process mid cycle I need to age the account and remove it after x days if it is not completed.

How do I capture the flow response stage in order to do this?
ie., SIGNUP --> "add signing up to global context" --> CODE SENT --> "add pending to account" --> CODE ENTERED --> "activate account"

I tried figuring out how to catch the responses from aws authenticator with no luck.

Comment: Authenticator doens't have a public API for catching Sign Up events directly. But you can try using JS hub events: https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/authentication/listening-for-auth-events/q/platform/js/

It'll emit a `signUp` event in particular (and `data` from signUp hub event should have relevant data for you.

Comment: @william-lee I have seen the hub stuff.  However that is not comprehensive enough.  That is basically signin, signin failure, and signout.  I am not even sure what signup is for.  The hub does explain Hub in general and not all the authentication dispatches.  Do you have an example how someone uses context with authenticator or would that be another question?